# Sequencing two independent futures with different error types

Tags: rust

I have code lined up as below :-

```
let done = client_a.
    .get_future(data)
    .then(move |result| {
        // further processing on result
        spawn a future here.
    });

tokio::run(done);
```

Now I have another future the result of which I want to process along with 'processing of result'.
However, that future is completely independent of `client_a` which implies :-

- both could have different error types.
- failure of one should not stop other one.

  ```
  let done = client_a.
      .get_future(data)
      .then(move |result| {
          // how to fit in 
          // client_b.get_future
          // here

          // further processing on both results
          spawn third future here.
      });

      tokio::run(done);
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both error and item types are heterogenous and you know *how many* futures you will chain, the simplest way to do so is to chain into an infallible `Future` (because that's what your remaining future really is) whose `Item` type is  a tuple of all the intermediate results.

This can be relatively simply implemented by simple chaining:

```
let future1_casted = future1.then(future::ok::<Result<_, _>, ()>);
let future2_casted = future2.then(future::ok::<Result<_, _>, ()>);

let chain = future1_casted
    .and_then(|result1| future2_casted.map(|result2| (result1, result2)));
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fabe33a9df047072bbbc7bf3fc76c40f)

The final future type is a tuple containing all the results of the futures.

If you do not know how many futures you are chaining, you will need to strengthen your requirements and explicitly know ahead of time the possible return types of your futures. Since it is not possible without macros to generate an arbitrary-sized tuple, you're going to need to store the intermediate results into a structure requiring homogeneous types.

To solve this problem, defining tuples containing your types, for example for errors, is required:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum MyError {
    Utf16Error(char::DecodeUtf16Error),
    ParseError(num::ParseIntError)
}

impl From<char::DecodeUtf16Error> for MyError {
    fn from(e: char::DecodeUtf16Error) -> Self {
        MyError::Utf16Error(e)
    }
}

impl From<num::ParseIntError> for MyError {
    fn from(e: num::ParseIntError) -> Self {
        MyError::ParseError(e)
    }
}
```

From there, combining futures follows the same route as before - turn a fallible future into an infallible `Result<_, _>` return, and combine then into a structure like a `Vec` with [`future::loop_fn()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.0/futures/future/fn.loop_fn.html)

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. However this misses the other point "Both futures must have the same error type, and if either finishes with an error then the other will be dropped and that error will be returned."

Comment: @ravi Adding extra. It won't be pretty, but it's the better way of doing it, as there is no real way to do it otherwise.

Comment: @ravi Edited with a crude way to do it. Ideally you'd wrap your futures to be infalliable *before* combining them.

Comment: Can't I sequence them using 'then' like second futures would execute after first one but somehow I can carry forward result of first one.

Comment: This calls for a better explanation of what you're actually trying to do. I assumed that you could drive them to completion independently - after all, if the first fails, was the second really independent of the first if you couldn't?

Comment: So they are independent in a sense that failure of one shouldn't affect the other one. Both should execute sequentially/simultaneously to produce data which will be stored in maps and used for spawning third future.

Comment: Then I will delete my answer and write an entirely different one :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199772/discussion-between-ravi-and-sebastien-renauld).